# .htaccess Rewrite URL - Adjust to correct path

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've moved a blog over to another host and there are several posts with links that are now broken. This is because I've moved the blog into a subdirectory /blog/. It was previously in the root directory.

I'm hoping I can redirect any URL requests that result in a 404 from:

```
http://example.com/2014/04/10/the-blog-post
```

TO

```
http://example.com/blog/2014/04/10/the-blog-post
```

So essentially all the htaccess file needs to do is add "blog" in before the query string IF the requested URL does not exist.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(?!blog) blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,DPI]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.

**Option 2**

For the last line, you can also use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!blog)(.*) blog/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: Hey, for some reason it caused a redirect loop. It put a bunch of `home2/accnt1092/public_html/blog` at the end of the URL

Comment: That's strange, as `(?!blog)` should prevent the rule from firing. Try the update (removed a slash, added the DPI flag). Also: did you use the `-MultiViews` options from the top?

Comment: Hey for the last line, I added a second option in case that's still not working for you: `RewriteRule ^(?!blog)(.*) blog/$1 [L,R]`

Comment: Both are still causing a loop. Same exact thing is happening... Not entirely sure what's causing this but anytime I put anything after `example.com/oaskd` it pends the direct path to that folder and loops it several times.

Comment: I copied and pasted word for word. All of it is there.

Comment: After `RewriteEngine On`, try adding `RewriteBase /`. Also, the htaccess should be in the document root folder (above blog), is that the case?

Comment: Okay `RewriteBase /` did the trick. The Option 2 however does not work for me. I went ahead with your original `RewriteRule` and it seems to work flawlessly!